How to identify Stereochemically active or inactive orbital?
I have a doubt regarding the distorted octahedral shape of XeF6 as a result of lone pair being in stereochemically active s orbital. The shape is perfect octahedral in [ICl6]- as in that, the lone pair is in stereochemically inactive s orbital.
I read some answers of questions similar to this which said that since s is spherical in shape, a Lone pair in s orbital would not lead to assymetry.
But in XeF6 also, the lone pair in s orbital right? How come this s orbital becomes stereochemically active and starts to interfere with the arrangement?
How to know when it is stereochemically active or inactive? What i am missing?

related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82303/what-is-a-stereochemically-active-or-inactive-s-orbital

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82350/what-is-the-molecular-structure-of-xenon-hexafluoride
